# Multiplication method inside JavaScript Class returning NAN

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, algorithm, next.js

I have a multiplication method inside a JavaScript Class that is supposed to multiply all elements of an array that are not undefined. I used for loop to check the type of each element that is number and push them to an empty array before using reduce method to multiply them. But the problem I'm having now is that the result is returning NAN. Please I would like to know what I'm doing wrong.

My code below.

```js
class Calculator {

    add(numbers) {
        let result = [];
        for (const i in numbers) {
           if (typeof numbers[i] === "number"){
            result.push(numbers[i])
           }
          
        }
        console.log(result.reduce(function (a, b) {
            return a + b;
          }, 0)); // This works as expected
      }

  multiply(numbers) {
    let result2 = [];
    for (const j in numbers) {
       if (typeof numbers[j] === "number"){
        result2.push(numbers[j])
       }
      
    }
    console.log(numbers.reduce((a, b) => a * b)); //This is returning NAN inside of the multiplication result
    
    
  }

  subtract(num1, num2) {
    return num1 - num2;
  }

  divide(num1, num2) {
    return num1 / num2;
  }
 
}
  
 let values = new Calculator();
 values.add([10, undefined, -1, 10, 100]);
 values.multiply([10, 5, 6, 'a']);
```

Comment: `numbers.reduce(...)` should be `result2.reduce(...)`. Descriptive variable names help to avoid mistakes like this!

Comment: Thank you @Robin Zigmond

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the **numbers.reduce** to **result2.reduce**. Refer updated code below.

```js
       class Calculator {

            add(numbers) {
                let result = [];
                for (const i in numbers) {
                    if (typeof numbers[i] === "number") {
                        result.push(numbers[i])
                    }

                }
                console.log(result.reduce(function (a, b) {
                    return a + b;
                }, 0)); // This works as expected
            }

            multiply(numbers) {
                let result2 = [];
                for (const j in numbers) {
                    if (typeof numbers[j] === "number") {
                        result2.push(numbers[j])
                    }

                }
                console.log(result2.reduce((a, b) => a * b)); //This is returning NAN inside of the multiplication result


            }

            subtract(num1, num2) {
                return num1 - num2;
            }

            divide(num1, num2) {
                return num1 / num2;
            }

        }

        let values = new Calculator();
        values.add([10, undefined, -1, 10, 100]);
        values.multiply([10, 5, 6, 'a']);
```